# Парсит только первые 2 страницы

Tags: php, парсер, phpquery

Пытаюсь научится делать парсеры. Сейчас с помощью библиотеки phpquery делаю простенький парсер. Не получается пройтись дальше 2 страниц каталога чтобы вытащить артикул и цену на товар. Парсит 2 страницы и цикл запускается снова. Дублирует 2 страницы по несколько раз.
 Прикрепляю свой код. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в том, что я записал не так. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

```js
<?php 
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

 require 'phpQuery-onefile.php';

function parser ($url,$start,$end) {

 if ($start < $end) {
 
  $file = file_get_contents($url);
  $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);

   foreach ($doc->find('.product-list') as $position) {
    $position = pq($position);

    $articul = $position->find('.name > span:even(1)')->text();
    $price = $position->find('.actions .price')->html();

    // echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>";
    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($articul);
    print_r($price);
    echo '</pre>'; 
   }
    $next = $doc->find('.pagination li a')->attr('href');

  if ( !empty($next) ) {
   $start++;
   parser($next, $start, $end);
  }
 } 
}



$url = "https://www.agro-center.com.ua/combines-a/spare-parts-for-grain-harvesters/john-deere-c/";
$start = 0;
$end = 4;
parser($url,$start,$end);

phpQuery::unloadDocuments();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто вы не правильно ищите следующую страницу, вы берете первую ссылку в пагинации, а на второй странице: первая ссылка будет на первую страницу (обратно). Поэтому у вас всегда и получается `1-2-1-2-1-2...`

Решение:

```
$next = $doc->find('.pagination li a')->attr('href');
```

Замените на:

```
$next = $doc->find('.pagination .active')->next()->find('a')->attr('href');
```

Тут мы берем первую ссылку после активного блока, т.е. на следующую страницу.

Comment: Господи, Вы ж мой спаситель! Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: @SlavaAwaken вы правы, есть у меня такая функция ;)